# jQuery cannot change the DOM with meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I'm using [Meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com) for a website I'm working on.  I can't seem to use javascript (or jQuery) to manipulate the DOM at all.

The code below does not change the #testDiv HTML, and there is nothing in the alert box.

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
        $("#testDiv").text("test");
        alert($("#testDiv").text());
});
```

My HTML is very basic:

```
    <div id="testDiv">
         this is a test
    </div>
```

Does anybody know whats going on?  Is this a problem with my jQuery, or Meteor.js?  Or am I just overlooking something simple?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that it's being run before the DOM is loaded. Can you provide more details?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, meteor.js automatically loads template and HTML files before any js file, but that may be the problem.

Comment: did you load jquery?

Comment: I did load jQuery through meteor's packaging system.

Comment: you need to run a onRendered(function(){}) to manipulate DOM elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) only executes when its reactive variables change. The best way to directly manipulate the DOM in meteor is in an [onRendered](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) callback. For example:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  $("#testDiv").text("test");
  alert($("#testDiv").text());
});
```

Comment: See, it was just a dumb little mistake :)  Thank you, that solved my problem.